# How can I make html table columns (only the ones with text) evenly spaced

Tags: html, css

I wondering if there is an easy way to do this via HTML / CSS.

I have a dynamic fixed-width table with 4 columns:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is always have all the columns with data have all the same width.

So if any column is completely empty, I want it to collapse and the remaining columns would all have the same width.

I know that my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTbGB/) is not correct, but I wanted to have one as a starting point.

I did review [How to get table cells evenly spaced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859180/how-to-get-table-cells-evenly-spaced), but is not exactly what I am looking for.
I also reviewed [Evenly spaced fixed-width columns - in a responsive setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662018/evenly-spaced-fixed-width-columns-in-a-responsive-setting), but that one also not the same.

**EDIT**:

`td:empty {display: none}`  is a not the solution because if another row has has text in that column, the table gets distorted.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTbGB/4/)

Comment: I think you need javascript for this

Comment: 4 columns means td {width:25%;} with table{table-layout:fixed;/*width:optionnal*/}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE

in case of more than one row :

Solution is as describe below, to have it work, you need `<tr>` to be displayed as a single table : http://jsfiddle.net/zTbGB/7/ http://jsfiddle.net/zTbGB/8/

```
tr {
    display:table;
     table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

=================================================

you can set : `table-layout:fixed` on table element.
http://jsfiddle.net/zTbGB/1/

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout

Then you can use the :empty selector :

```
td:empty {display:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zTbGB/3/

Comment: I updated the question.  This does not work correctly.  Thank you

Comment: i updated my answer, tr displayed as a table fixes it .

Comment: For me, declaring "table-layout: fixed; width:100%;" for the table itself, solved the issue (but I do not have empty columns). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTbGB/2/). Seems to work well. In the CSS below, I'm using the ::empty pseudo selector. That selector won't work in IE8 or less, so if you're supporting IE8, then you'll need to augment this code with some javascript to hide those empty `<td>`'s.

**CSS**

```
table
{
    width: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td:empty { display: none; }
```

Comment: I updated the question.  This does not work correctly.

Comment: I recommend you [check out this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764404/calculate-and-set-colspan-value-dynamically). With some tweaking, it should be able to help you. There is no way in CSS to be able to dynamically assign `colspan` values to your HTML.

Comment: You have a work around by breaking the table into many ones displaying <tr> as single tables : http://jsfiddle.net/zTbGB/8/

Answer (score 1):

I have tried code for you using jQuery :) , you can use following code using jQuery:

```
$("#parent td").each(function() {


     if ($(this).text() == ''){
         var val=$(this).val();
        //alert(len);
     $(this).remove();


     }

});
var len=$("#parent td").length;
         var wit=100/len;
     //wit=wit+"%";
$("table td").width(wit + "%");
```

updated here http://jsfiddle.net/zTbGB/6/